# How to transfer data from state to mapdispatchtoprops?

Tags: reactjs, redux

How to transfer data from state to mapdispatchtoprops? I get the url of the image and write it to state, then I want to pass this url to dispatch

```js
// State
const [imgUrl, setUrl] = useState(null);

// Map dispatch
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
 const { api } = ownProps;
 return {
  fetchLoaded: () => {
   api.addData(imgUrl)
  }
 };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify your arguments in `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
    fetchLoaded: (imgUrl) => {
        api.addData(imgUrl)
    }
```

Then pass those arguments when calling the function:

```
    props.fetchLoaded(imgUrl);
```